# redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: unix, redis, amazon-elasticache

we are trying to using Amazon ElastiCache in place of Redis.

From Dev Box connection getting created but while accessing getting the below error

```
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:47)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:36)
at org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37)
at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.convertJedisAccessException(JedisConnection.java:196)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.hGetAll(JedisConnection.java:2536)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations$13.doInRedis(DefaultHashOperations.java:223)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations$13.doInRedis(DefaultHashOperations.java:220)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:191)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:153)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:86)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.entries(DefaultHashOperations.java:220)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultBoundHashOperations.entries(DefaultBoundHashOperations.java:101)
at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:432)
at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:402)
at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:245)
at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:327)
at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:344)
at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:390)
at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:217)
at com.operative.dashboard.web.multitenancy.filter.TenantContextFilter.setTenantAndUser(TenantContextFilter.java:89)
at com.operative.dashboard.web.multitenancy.filter.TenantContextFilter.doFilter(TenantContextFilter.java:75)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
at com.operative.dashboard.web.logging.filter.LongRequestDetectionFilter.doFilter(LongRequestDetectionFilter.java:69)
at com.operative.dashboard.web.logging.filter.LongRequestDetectionFilter.doFilter(LongRequestDetectionFilter.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:167)
at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1629)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:317)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:201)
at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.read(RedisInputStream.java:180)
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processBulkReply(Protocol.java:158)
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:132)
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processMultiBulkReply(Protocol.java:183)
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:134)
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:192)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:282)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getBinaryMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:218)
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.hgetAll(BinaryJedis.java:865)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.hGetAll(JedisConnection.java:2534)
... 55 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:127)
at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:195)
```

same ElastiCache instance i am able to connect using local.
we gave allowed the Devbox IP from the Amazon ElastiCache .

Not too much sure about IP and VPC. lookes like some access or time out issue.

thanks in Advance

Comment: are you sure your redis / elasticcache IP are right? is there a firewall sowewhere that could hide your elasticcache?

Comment: hi @jeorfevre IP is correct cause it is creating the connection.only while accessing it is giving this error